# How to make circle images in NSTableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to make a mac app and in my tableview i have a label and imageview

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    NSString *cellId = @"Feature";
    NSTableCellView *cellView =[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:cellId owner:self];

    if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"FeaturesColumn"]){
        if([cellId isEqualToString: @"Feature"]){
            CALayer *imageLayer = cellView.imageView.layer;
            [imageLayer setCornerRadius:30.0f];
            [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
            [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [cellView.imageView setLayer:imageLayer];
            [cellView.textField setStringValue:[_features objectAtIndex:row]];
            return cellView;
        }

    }
    return cellView;
}
```

But whenever i run the simulation, all i get are rectangular images

Comment: use masking of image with some circle mask image to show your images in circle. example : http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Comment: This is for the iphone though isnt it?

Comment: masking is the easiest way to show up images in shapes and design.

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
// Get your image somehow
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

    // Begin a new image that will be the new image with the rounded corners
    // (here with the size of an UIImageView)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

    // Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds
    cornerRadius:10.0] addClip];
    // Draw your image
    [image drawInRect:imageView.bounds];

    // Get the image, here setting the UIImageView image
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Lets forget about that we were drawing
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Do i need to import uikit or something for these classes?

Comment: UIKit is needed if it's already in *.pch* file then doesn't need to import otherwise yes you have to

Comment: This answer is for iOS rather than for OS X. These functions do not exist in Cocoa.